# Disable/Grey-out screen or components during long validation

Tags: install4j

I have a screen that requires validation logic that is potentially long-running (e.g. on a slow machine, perhaps as long as ten seconds). During validation, install4j disables input, which is good. However, the screen does not give the appearance/L&F of being disabled. For example, labels and input fields are not greyed-out. I would like the screen or controls to look disabled during the validation period.

I've looked through some of the install4j API docs in hopes of finding something like screen.setEnabled( boolean ), but could not find anything along these lines.

I have also tried using the following code in the validation script to perform this task, but it doesn't seem to work. That is, all of the screen's controls still have the L&F of enabled during a long-running validation:

```
for( FormComponent fc : formEnvironment.getFormComponents() )
{
    fc.setEnabled( false );
}
```

Any suggestions out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation expression is executed on the event dispatch thread, so the fact that you cannot access any fields is simply due to the EDT being unavailable.

For long-running validations, add a "Run script" action to the screen with the "Failure strategy" property set to "Return to the parent screen". The form components will be disabled automatically with the appropriate visual feedback. If the validation fails, return null from the script and the screen will be shown again.

You can also show progress during the validation: On the form screen, add a "Progress display" form component with the "Hide initially" property selected. Then, add a "Set the progress bar" action before the "Run script" action that does the validation. You can also control progress programmatically, like this:

```
context.getProgressInterface().setIndeterminateProgress(true);
```

Comment: Ingo thanks, as always, for your help! The other part of this question, which I forgot to ask, was how to show progress, such as an hourglass cursor. But you anticipated this for me. Thank you again. I think this solution will work nicely.